# Error cuando hago push a un repositorio en google cloud

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, sourcetree

Ya van dos veces que intento hacer push y no puedo.

me sale el siguiente error

```sh
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to https://source.developers.google.com/p/newdiscoverymedia/r/AR_PRESS_V2
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://source.developers.google.com/p/newdiscoverymedia/r/AR_PRESS_V2.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/101), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: Client error: https://source.cloud.google.com/onboarding/welcome from HTTP 405
batch response: Client error: https://source.cloud.google.com/onboarding/welcome from HTTP 405
batch response: Client error: https://source.cloud.google.com/onboarding/welcome from HTTP 405


error: failed to push some refs to 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/newdiscoverymedia/r/AR_PRESS_V2'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Por lo que logro entender tiene que ver con los lfs, pero ya en mi gitattribute todos los lfs y cuando hago el commit no me da ningun error, solo es a la hora del push.

espero me puedan ayudar.

saludos cordiales

Comment: No tengo experiencia con LFS pero por lo que veo en el mensaje, te está dando la forma de deshabiitarlo (por lo menos lo de los lockings.... para ese repositorio particular). Corre: `git config lfs.https://source.developers.google.com/p/newdiscoverymedia/r/AR_PRESS_V2.git/info/lfs.locksverify false`. Comentario aparte al hacer un push, si vas a empujar tu rama local a una rama del mismo nombre, no tienes que indicar ambos nombres.... es decir, en vez de usar `master:master`, `master` es suficiente.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la antepenúltima oración? Parece que falta algo: *pero ya en mi gitattribute todos los lfs y cuando hago el commit no me da ningun error,*

Comment: @PabloLozano las oraciones estan completas. tampoco entiendo porque sale ese error, tiene el track de los lfs que necesito y no me sale ningun warning cuando hago el commit (cuando no tiene tackeado algun lfs te sale un warning de eso, y no me slae nada). estuve viendo unos documentos dw git. y creo que es algo nuevo que se esta implementando llamado locking, pero no esta disponibles en todos los repositorios, entonces creo que se debe desactivar.
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking